# Adding to ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::MysqlAdapter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-plugins

For general knowledge and entertainment purposes I am trying to add some behavoiur to Rails. What I am looking for is simply to run a Mysql "EXPLAIN" statement before every select statement that Rails runs. I think this should work ok but I am getting the error:

/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.1.0/lib/active_support/core_ext/module/aliasing.rb:32:in `alias_method': undefined method`select_with_explain' for class `ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::MysqlAdapter' (NameError)

This class is located in the initializers dir. Here is the code:

```
    module Explanifier

      def self.included(base)

        base.class_eval do
          extend ClassMethods
          alias_method_chain :select, :explain


        end
      end
      module ClassMethods
        def select_with_explain(sql, name = nil)
          puts "testing!!!"
          execute('EXPLAIN ' + sql, name)
          select_without_explain(sql, name)
        end
      end

    end



    class ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::MysqlAdapter
      include Explanifier
    end
```

Can someone explain what I am missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

put your alias_method_chain in your ClassMethods module. because you define the method like classMethod and alias a InstanceMethod

```
    module Explanifier

      def self.included(base)

        base.class_eval do
          extend ClassMethods



        end
      end
      module ClassMethods
        def select_with_explain(sql, name = nil)
          puts "testing!!!"
          execute('EXPLAIN ' + sql, name)
          select_without_explain(sql, name)
        end
        alias_method_chain :select, :explain
      end

    end
```

Answer (score 0):

Just stumbled upon this.

You can't call it from within `base.class_eval` and you obviously can't put it inside the `ClassMethods` module. (Since there is no `select` method in `ClassMethods` module, is there?)

The way to go is to do this:

```
def self.included(base)
  base.extend ClassMethods
  class << base
    alias_method_chain :select, :explain
  end
end
```

You just need to access it through a ghost class over there. Hope it helps.